# Encoding in Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

Is there any way to set encoding (change `UTF-8` to `WINDOWS1252`) in Laravel Excel when downloading a CSV? I can do:

```
\Excel::create('Exemple', function(LaravelExcelWriter $excel) {
    // ...
})->download('csv');
```

But I cannot set the encoding... Maybe I missed something?

Comment: why you need to use legacy encoding?

Comment: Because Microsoft Excel does not open UTF8 CSV properly (without explaining complex things to do to non-tech people).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski haha! No... Did you downvote for this? Or is it someone else?

Comment: then why you use Excell writer if you exporting plain CSV?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I use it because i use it elsewhere for something else, so for more consistency (maybe I'm wrong) I thought : "I should use the lib everywhere I need to do something about sheets"

Answer (score -1):

Excel tool is for excel files, not for everything. You should use right tool for the task.

If you are about to create CSV file then you can simply use even `file_put_contents()` or use ordinary `fputs()` in a loop along with `iconv()` which should be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: I need to create the correct header for downloading too. So all this things are easy to do AND to read with Laravel Excel (2 lines). I am sorry to say that, you seems a bit rude in your answer, so don't be upset by my comment. I think Laravel Excel is still the right tool (if encodage would have works). It supports CSV and it has all function to send it, store it, etc. I know how to use native PHP functions, but it will be 15 lines of code (loops, send header, config, etc.), Laravel Excel make it clear. It's about sheets, a csv is sometimes a kind of sheet.

Comment: Hey I asked you not to be rude :)! I was in vacation. Don't answer if you just want to be nasty. I have done something else during this time, and I just re-opened my todo list. The question is not about that. A question on SO can help other people too. And you answered with opinion.

Comment: @Marcin_Orlowski Hi, Laravel Excel tool can easily generate Excel's compliant CSV files and the OP is using it for other purposes. Please answer to the question of the OP or don't answer at all.